# Soap, call a recovery service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I am new to SOAP. For a project, I need to use "[Force.com Toolkit for PHP](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP)".

I made the first call to open a Salesforce session and retrieve the session ID , which will be used to call the recovery service of customer information. ( It's ok, i have the ID session)

I know that the customer information flows is called using the session ID obtained with the first call, but **i don't how to do the second call** ! I also have another WSDL file  ( CallInListCustomer.wsdl.xml )

I also the customers informations flow addresses (found in WSDL ). I'm not sure , but i must the call in "post" format...

can you help me ?

```
<?php
session_start();

define("USERNAME", "my_username");
define("PASSWORD", "my_password");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "my_token");

require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');

$mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("Partner.wsdl.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

// Now we can save the connection info for the next page
$_SESSION['location'] = $mySforceConnection->getLocation();
$_SESSION['sessionId'] = $mySforceConnection->getSessionId();

$sessionId = $_SESSION['sessionId'];

echo $sessionId;

// Here, i don't know how to call the recovery service of customer information with allInListCustomer.wsdl.xml

?>
```

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution, here my code :

```
<?php
// salesforce.com Username, Password and TOken
define("USERNAME", "My_username");
define("PASSWORD", "My_password");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "My_token");

// from PHP-toolkit ( https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP )
require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');

$mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("Partner.wsdl.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

// I Get the IDSESSION
$sessionId = $mySforceConnection->getSessionId();

// I create a new soapClient with my WSDL
$objClient = new SoapClient("my_service.wsdl.xml", array('trace' => true));

// I create the header
$strHeaderComponent_Session = "<SessionHeader><sessionId>$sessionId</sessionId></SessionHeader>";
$objVar_Session_Inside = new SoapVar($strHeaderComponent_Session, XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);
$objHeader_Session_Outside = new SoapHeader('https://xxxxx.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/myservice', 'SessionHeader', $objVar_Session_Inside);
$objClient->__setSoapHeaders(array($objHeader_Session_Outside));

// i call the service
$objResponse = $objClient->getinfo(array ( 'Zone' => "123456"));

// here i get the result in Json
$json = json_encode( (array)$objResponse);
echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

Create separate file to store salesforce org details.

### SFConfig.php

```js
<?php
/*----------------------------------------------------------------
 *    We will define salesforce user anem and password with token.
 *    This file we used / include in every time when we need to 
 *    communicate withy salesforce.  
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------*/

$USERNAME = "Your salesforce user name";
$PASSWORD = "Your password with security token";
?>
```

Get account data from salesforce

### GetAccountData.php

```js
<?php
 // SET SOAP LIB DIRCTORY PATH
 define("SOAP_LIB_FILES_PATH", "/<Put Your file location>/soapclient");
 // Access sf config file
 require_once ('/<Put Your file location>/SFConfig.php');
 
 // Access partner client php lib file
 require_once (SOAP_LIB_FILES_PATH.'/SforcePartnerClient.php');
 
 try {
  echo "\n******** Inside the try *******\n";
  
  // Sf connection using ( SOAP ) partner WSDL
  $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
  $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_LIB_FILES_PATH.'/YourWSDLName.wsdl.xml');
  $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
  
  echo "\n******** Login with salesforce is done *******\n";
  
  
  
  // query for featch Versand data with last run datetime
  $query = "SELECT Id, Name
      FROM Account;
  
  
  
  
  // Send query to salesforce
  $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
  // Store the query result
  $queryResult = new QueryResult($response);
  
  $isError = false ;
  echo "Results of query '$query'<br/><br/>\n";
  // Show result array
  for ($queryResult->rewind(); $queryResult->pointer < $queryResult->size; $queryResult->next()) {
   $record = $queryResult->current();
   // Id is on the $record, but other fields are accessed via
   // the fields object
   echo "\nVersand value : ".$record->Abmelder__c."\n";
   
  }
  
   
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  $GLOBALS['isTimeEnter'] = true;
  echo "entered catch****\n";
  echo "Exception ".$e->faultstring."<br/><br/>\n";
  
  
 }
?>
```

Also if you want to call another services then just call using "$mySforceConnection" variable as per above.

For Example: (Create Contact)

```html
$records = array();

$records[0] = new SObject();
$records[0]->fields = array(
    'FirstName' => 'John',
    'LastName' => 'Smith',
    'Phone' => '(510) 555-5555',
    'BirthDate' => '1957-01-25'
);
$records[0]->type = 'Contact';

$records[1] = new SObject();
$records[1]->fields = array(
    'FirstName' => 'Mary',
    'LastName' => 'Jones',
    'Phone' => '(510) 486-9969',
    'BirthDate' => '1977-01-25'
);
$records[1]->type = 'Contact';

$response = $mySforceConnection->create($records);

$ids = array();
foreach ($response as $i => $result) {
    echo $records[$i]->fields["FirstName"] . " "
            . $records[$i]->fields["LastName"] . " "
            . $records[$i]->fields["Phone"] . " created with id "
            . $result->id . "<br/>\n";
    array_push($ids, $result->id);
}
```

Please check below link for more details:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP

Comment: Thanks, but i need to use 2 WSDL files. One for get the ID session ( it's ok for this ). now, i need to use the second WSDL in my code ( CallInListCustomer.wsdl.xml ) and use a function from this file for get the customers list. Have you got a idea ?

Comment: Why you need second WSDL file? Use Partner wsdl and do your operation. Also, if you login with first wsdl and want to use second wsdl for other operation then that may be not possible.